# Embeded Object in Java - Enum

Tags: java, model

I have an Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
public class Person {
  @Embedded
  private Item;

}
```

I want to add an embeded object that contains enum into my entity

```
public class Item{

  public ItemEnum items;
}
```

How do I add `Item` as an embeded object in `Person` and I want to save value of `items` as a `column in Person`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this...

```
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @Column(name = "ITEM")
  private Item item;
```

Comment: I need to save `items` which is a `ItemEnum` type in Item. I dont want to save `Item` Object. Item is not Enum. ItemEnum is enum.

Comment: Move the 'Enumerated' annotation on to 'items' then, and annotate Item with 'Embeddable'.